# data display in phpmyadmin and php script

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I have a page that has been filled form by user and submit.
everything is OK in phpMyAdmin and it have displayed data correctly.
But some data has been displayed correct and some data has been displayed incorrect in php page. The connection to MySQL is Unicode. Even I've changed browser text encoding but nothing has been changed.
the data is in persian unicode.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: You have to set the fields type to Unicode in phpmyadmin, in php try to run this query after your connection `$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

Comment: field type have set to Unicode nothing change.

Comment: `CHARACTER SET utf8`?  Does phpmyadmin have a utf8 setting?  Is there a `<meta ... charset=utf-8>` in html?

Comment: What does the incorrect data look like?